# .htaccess option -indexes redirect?

Tags: .htaccess

In .htaccess, we can use this code :

```
Option -Indexes
```

to protect people loading our directory.

However, how can we do this ?

```
Option -Indexes [redirect to /index.html]
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex

Comment: But I need it for _directories_ like _/css_!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just rewrite all requests to *directories* to your index page:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ /index.html [R=301,L]
```

(wrote this without having a system at hand, hope there's no typo...)

Explanation: since automatic indexes are only generated when a *directory* is requested by the browser, this *should* be safe. I am currently not sure about the implications of `.htaccess` style file usage. This also makes rewriting complex, error prone and slooooow. If you have access the real server configuration always prefer that!

Comment: `301` is maybe not the best redirect to use here?! since you are saying that **every** requested file has been permanently moved to `index.html`. So this will be valid **forever**.

Comment: @MA-Maddin The rule is only applied to _directories_ getting requested, nothing else.

Comment: yes, thats right, but I thought if someone call `example.com/css` that all requests that are coming later to `example.com/css/style.css` would be redirected as well (since the 301 is cached forever on client side and server won't be asked again). But that seems not the case, as I have just tested it. Btw: `RewriteRule -` does not work but `RewriteRule .` does.

Comment: @MA-Maddin It actually is true that `-` does not work as a pattern any more in newer versions of the apache http server. Best replacement is `^`...